# Send email with fresh .apk to specified users in case of git push

Tags: android, git

I would like to know if there is some way to ask git (or some other service) to send a fresh version of .apk file (which is stored in /bin directory of my project) to the specified users list via email just after pushing to a remote repository?

Consider that /bin directory of the project is not staged by git.

Answer (score 2):

That's the use of a `git hook`. Starting from `git 1.8.2` there's a git `pre-push` hook you can use to execute some command just before doing the `push`.

You can read how `git hooks` work here: [git hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

Here's an example of script for a `pre-push` hook  [example of git pre-push hook](https://github.com/git/git/blob/87c86dd14abe8db7d00b0df5661ef8cf147a72a3/templates/hooks--pre-push.sample)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately I use 1.7.4 version for my project and if I understand correctly it has different hooks with 1.8.2, so do you know if there a some way to change hooks in the current project?

Answer (score 0):

install a post-receive hook on the server where you push to.
you can place a shell script to do whatever you want there.
this includes sending an notification email with optional attachments.

doing it server-side ensures that it will be executed no matter who pushes with what local hooks installed.

more info: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks

Comment: ps: i missed the /bin part of the question. sorry. with this requirement the hook needs to be executed locally (or at least somewhere where the binaries are available), and pre-push is better suited, see Altropos answer above. keep in mind that this requires the hook to be installed in every relevant clone.